# cannot invoke reduce with an argument list of type swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

When i upgrade swift 1.2 to swift 2.0 following error occurs

> cannot invoke reduce with an argument list of type

here is code

```
let escaped = reduce(string, "") { string, character in
    string + (character == mark ? "\(mark)\(mark)" : "\(character)")
```

can you help me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce()` is a method for collections such as arrays so you have to call it on the list of the characters you can access using the `characters` property of the string, not on the whole string itself:

```
let escaped = string.characters.reduce("") { string, character in
    string + (character == mark ? "\(mark)\(mark)" : "\(character)")
}
```