# Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(String, (String) -> String)'

Tags: swift, string, perfect

I am trying to convert Swift 3 to Swift 4 for a [repo](https://github.com/PerfectExamples/Perfect-Authentication-Demo) on github. Here is a function that blocks me.

```
func times(_ n: Int) -> String {
    return (0..<n).reduce("") { $0 + self } 
}
```

The error Xcode gives is:

> "Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(String, (String) -> String)'"

I looked at Apple's official page and found [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907677-reduce) and [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce), and someone's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690771/cannot-invoke-reduce-with-an-argument-list-of-type-swift-2-0). Have tried the code below but I still can't get it to work. Please point out what I am missing.

```
return (0..<n).character.reduce("") { string, character in
                (0..<n) + self }

return (0..<n).character.reduce("") { $0 + self }
```

Here `$0` refers to the closure's first argument (I think). Then we can **self** property to refer to the current instance within its own instance methods.

Comment: Could you please provide what is self.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: To clarify the question, you should indicate where (in which class/struct/protocol) the times function is declared.  Since the function is concatenating self with a reduce() closure parameter that starts out with a String, we can conclude that this is part of an extension to String (but we shouldn't have to make that kind of assumption).  Also, because of the function's name (times) it seems likely that the purpose is to repeat the current string (self) n times.  And finally, the original code would not have worked in Swift 3 so there is probably more to this than a Swift 3-4 conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closure will be receiving two parameters and you're only using one ($0).   You could use $0.0 in the closure or simply use the string constructor that does the same thing without reduce:

```
func times(_ n: Int) -> String 
{ return String(repeating:self, count:n) }
```

OR, if you want to use Python like multiplication to repeat a string, you could add an operator:

```
extension String
{
    static func *(lhs:String,rhs:Int) -> String
    { return String(repeating:lhs, count:rhs) }
}

// then, the following will work nicely:

"blah " * 10  // ==> "blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah "
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what are you going to do. It was hard to get it out what reduce exactly do, but you must understand that the main point of this function needed to reduce the array into one variable.

Take a look on example:

```
let items = ["one", "two", "three"]
let final = items.reduce("initial") { text, item in "\(text), \(item)" }
print(final) // initial, one, two, three
```

In closure the `text` is a cumulating string. The initial value is setted as a parameter. `"initial"` in our example. At the first iteration the text would be `initial, one`. At second: `initial, one, two`. And so on. That's because we setted a rule how to reduce the array: `"\(text), \(item)"`

---

In your example:

```
func times(_ n: Int) -> String {
    return (0..<n).reduce("") { $0 + self } 
}
```

1. First we create an array with n items by this `(0..<n)`: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4..]
2. Then we set an initial value as an empty string.
3. Next can't know what you need.

Maybe you need a result string as `0123456789..`, then there a code:

```
let reduced = (0..<n).reduce("") { text, value in text + "\(value)" }
```

Hope that would help you =)

Comment: works!   <3, so the text is declared on the fly?  could be any sting? And in your example, we see there is an items array, then we can  we setted a rule as " item in "\(text), \(item)" "  How come just with "(0..<n),  you know we should use "  "\(value)" ".